# Records exists but not found by query

Tags: php, mysql

I'm making a query to my database, but the query always return empty. If I copy the query and paste it directly to mysql, it show one record, as it should be.
This is my query in php:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM disponibilities WHERE st_week = '" . 
$st_week . "' AND en_week = '" . $en_week . "' AND boat = '" . 
$_POST['boat'] . "'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $disponibility = $row;
    }
} else {
    echo "0";
    echo $_POST['boat'];
}
```

And this is the query (echo of the previous query) that show one record if used in phpmyadmin:

```
SELECT * FROM disponibilities WHERE st_week = '2021-11-13' AND en_week = '2021-11-20' AND boat = 'sapphire'
```

I've tried converting the date in this way, but still don't work

```
$sql= "SELECT * FROM disponibilities WHERE st_week = 
STR_TO_DATE('$st_week','%Y-%m-%d') AND en_week = STR_TO_DATE('$en_week','%Y-%m-%d')";
```

EDIT:
this is my phpmyadmin query response:
[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237518/discussion-on-question-by-johnnydeppa-records-exists-but-not-found-by-query).

Answer (score 0):

try to run

```
    SELECT * FROM disponibilities WHERE st_week = '2021-11-13' AND en_week = '2021-11-20' AND boat = 'sapphire';
```

this query from your code what i mean is that run the query with static values instead of variables and see if it returns anything if it does then you are getting wrong value in your variables...

let me if this is the problem if not also so that i can help you further...

Comment: Thank but it does not work, can't connect to the table

Comment: does it give you an error or it just return nothing

Comment: Just return nothing :/

Comment: if you are able to share the tables and php code with me via github i would be able to check the problem and give you a proper solution...

Comment: Thank you but your name is just for kidding right? just kidding, no problem i can share

Comment: well it just a name no need to get scared... any way i will be waiting for your reply...

Comment: can you please give me some instructions on how to share it with you?

Comment: upload your code to github.com if you don't know how to do it here is a good video you can watch and learn 

https://medium.com/@sauravbhagat_10426/how-to-upload-code-to-github-6db1c8ff56aa

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JGRVdxvimdg